# Converting dd° mm.mmm' to dd.ddddd° (latitude & longitude) in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, gps

I have GPS coordinates in the form

Lat = 3648.5518
Lon = 17443.258

I want to convert then to the more traditional format

Lat = -36.8091667 
Lon = 174.7209667

I can do this through string manipulation as shown below. However this approach seems very "wordy".Is there a better way (any inbuilt functionality) to achieve this conversion in Python 3.4? my searches have come up blank. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Steve (New to python/programming)

```
Lat = 3648.5518
Lat = str(Lat)
Latdd = float(Lat[:2])
Latmmmmm = float(Lat[2:])
Latddmmmm = Latdd+(Latmmmmm/60.0)
print(Latddmmmm)


Lon = 17443.258
Lon = str(Lon)
Londd = float(Lon[:3])
Lonmmmmm = float(Lon[3:])
Londdmmmm = Londd+(Lonmmmmm/60.0)
print(Londdmmmm)
```

Comment: is the negative sign in the example correct? It doesn't match the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the input is an abuse of decimal notation to place write deg min as 100*deg + min.

You can extract the degree, minute and second parts with modulo division. Split into two functions for clarity.

```
def dm(x):
    degrees = int(x) // 100
    minutes = x - 100*degrees

    return degrees, minutes

def decimal_degrees(degrees, minutes):
    return degrees + minutes/60 

print (decimal_degrees(*dm(3648.5518)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [JamesK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40692700/21268873), their approach doesn't work for southern/negative latitudes. The below code will work:

```
def dm(x):
    south = False
    
    if x<0:
        south = True
        x = abs(x)
        
    degrees = int(x) // 100
    minutes = x - 100*degrees
    
    x = degrees + minutes/60
    if south:
        x = -x
    return x

print (dm(3648.5518))
```